# Remove rows that exist in another dataframe using two columns

Tags: r

Using this:

```
list_one[!list_one$letters %in% list_two$letters,]
```

it is possible to remove rows from one dataframe that exist in another.

How can we transform this command in other to check two columns from both data frames.

example

```
list_one[![list_one$letters, list_one$id] %in% [list_two$letters, list_two$letters],]
```

Comment: Something like this? `list_one[!list_one$letters %in% list_two$letters | !list_two$letters %in% list_two$letters,]`

Comment: Yes, use `dplyr::anti_join` and then try out different values for `by` argument